# How does NotificationChannel from the function StartExpenseAnalysisCommand of Amazon Textract works? AmazonTextract unable to publish msg to SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-textract

Good afternoon,

I am working with this service [StartExpenseAnalysisCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-client-textract/Interface/StartExpenseAnalysisCommandInput/) where there is a parameter that I am interested in using called NotificationChannel, where I pass my TopicArn (SNS), so basically my function is the following:

```
   const command = new StartExpenseAnalysisCommand({
      DocumentLocation: {
        S3Object: {
          Bucket: fileObj.s3.bucket.name,
          Name: fileObj.s3.object.key,
        },
      },
      NotificationChannel: {
        SNSTopicArn: process.env.SNS_TOPIC_ARN,
        RoleArn: process.env.ROLE_ARN,
      },
    });
    const response = await textractClient.send(command);
```

To explain what I want to do:

- I have this Lambda Function that start StartExpenseAnalysisCommand. After completion, it is suppose to publish to the SNSTopicArn I created in NotificationChannel with the JobID.
- This will publish to the SNS sending the JobId, and triggers my second Lambda Function, which will receive the event and extract the data with GetExpenseAnalysisCommand.

The issue I am facing is that it never triggers when I process the first function. I already confirmed that it receives the JobId and also confirmed that it is subscribed, but it never publish it.

[Subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLyMm.png)

I also tried publishing a message manually from the aws console, and it works, it triggers the lambda function, so the problem might be with the NotificationChannel.

[Manual publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JElki.png)

This is my serverless.yml where I also defined the permissions required for it which are sns:Publish and lambda:InvokeFunction:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  memorySize: 128
  region: ${env:AWS_REGION}
  stage: ${opt:stage,'dev'}
  environment:
    # APP
    APP_STAGE: ${env:APP_STAGE}
    APP_SERVICE_NAME: ${env:APP_SERVICE_NAME}
    AWS_SQS_QUEUE_URL: !Ref MySQSQueue
    AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: ${env:AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}
    DEVELOPMENT_PATH: ${env:DEVELOPMENT_PATH}
    EXCHANGE_RATE_API: ${env:EXCHANGE_RATE_API}
    MESSAGING_QUEUE: ${env:MESSAGING_QUEUE}
    SNS_TOPIC_ARN: ${env:SNS_TOPIC_ARN}
    ROLE_ARN: ${env:ROLE_ARN}
    # SNS_TOPIC_ARN: !GetAtt AmazonTextractMyTopicName.TopicArn
    # ROLE_ARN: arn:aws:iam::${env:AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/${env:APP_SERVICE_NAME}-${env:APP_STAGE}-${env:AWS_REGION}-lambdaRole
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - sqs:SendMessage
            - sqs:ReceiveMessage
            - sqs:DeleteMessage
          Resource: !GetAtt MySQSQueue.Arn
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - textract:StartExpenseAnalysis
            - textract:GetExpenseAnalysis
          Resource: "*"
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - s3:GetObject
            - s3:PutObject
          Resource: "*"
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - sns:Publish
          Resource: !GetAtt AmazonTextractMyTopicName.TopicArn
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - lambda:InvokeFunction
          Resource: "*"

functions:
  startExpenseAnalysisJob:
    handler: src/functions/startExpenseAnalysisJob.handler
    timeout: 180
    maximumRetryAttempts: 0
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn: !GetAtt MySQSQueue.Arn
          batchSize: 1
  processExpenseAnalysisJob:
    handler: src/functions/processExpenseAnalysisJob.handler
    events:
      - sns:
          arn: !GetAtt AmazonTextractMyTopicName.TopicArn
          topicName: AmazonTextractMyTopicName-${self:provider.stage}

resources:
  Resources:
    # Official Docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html
    MySQSQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: SQS-${self:provider.stage}
        VisibilityTimeout: 360

    AmazonTextractMyTopicName:
      Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
      Properties:
        TopicName: AmazonTextractMyTopicName-${self:provider.stage}

custom:
  serverless-offline-sqs:
    autoCreate: true
    apiVersion: "2012-11-05"
    endpoint: http://0.0.0.0:9324
    region: ${self:provider.region}
    accessKeyId: root
    secretAccessKey: root
    skipCacheInvalidation: false
```

Also, should I use subscribe my SQS to the topic? Right now I am just having my second Lambda with a trigger event with only SNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, following this guide: [docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/api-async-roles.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/api-async-roles.html)

Follow this part: **Giving Amazon Textract Access to Your Amazon SNS Topic**. the step 14, where you should find the trust policy and add it to your role (In the aws console) select your role => Find Trust Relationship => Edit Trust Policy.

The problem I had was related to the permissions, specifically in the trust relationships part.

Thank you, hope this helps for those who works with this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).